# Mostly Failing HTTPWebRequest over SSL in Azure - The Underlying Connection was Closed

Tags: azure, ssl

So having a strange issue in Azure that we could use some assistance on.  We've taken the liberty of isolating it down to an HTTPWebRequest (POST - GET works fine) over SSL.  This particular request to our client works reliably on any computer, however, the moment we spin up an Azure VM and run it, it fails 90-95% of the time.  The fact that it works is what makes this so difficult.

One thing that makes this even more odd, is that this same request, in Azure works 100% of the time once proxied by Fiddler.  Installed Fiddler to help debug and was unable to reproduce the issue.  Exit Fiddler and the problem shows up once again.

Most likely something to do with SSL, however, the fact that it worked at all is what has me completely baffled.  We've been able to capture a successful tracelog and a failed tracelog from the Azure VM.

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly..

Another factor is that the client utilizes a product called DataPower, but uncertain if that is just extra noise in this thread.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I just spent six hours thinking I was going insane chasing something similar. In my case, I was using DotNetOpenAuth for a single-sign on implementation, just like my five other servers. But this new server would vomit 99% of the time:

```
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: Error occurred while sending a direct message or getting the response. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameBody(Int32 readBytes, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.StandardWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.UntrustedWebRequestHandler.GetResponse(HttpWebRequest request, DirectWebRequestOptions options)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis.Yadis.Request(IDirectWebRequestHandler requestHandler, Uri uri, Boolean requireSsl, String[] acceptTypes)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.Yadis.Yadis.Discover(IDirectWebRequestHandler requestHandler, UriIdentifier uri, Boolean requireSsl)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.UriDiscoveryService.Discover(Identifier identifier, IDirectWebRequestHandler requestHandler, Boolean& abortDiscoveryChain)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.IdentifierDiscoveryServices.Discover(Identifier identifier)
   at DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.AuthenticationRequest.Create(Identifier userSuppliedIdentifier, OpenIdRelyingParty relyingParty, Realm realm, Uri returnToUrl, Boolean createNewAssociationsAsNeeded)
```

To really question my sanity,

- Visiting the SSL endpoint in the Web browser worked just fine
- Turning on Fiddler capturing made it work, and turning it off made it not work
- It really did work by itself about 1% of the time
- Using an `HttpWebRequest` in a console app to the same endpoint worked, but switching to DotNetOpenAuth (which appears to be doing more or less the same thing) caused it to mostly not work

After checking about every possible thing that can be checked, I went into the Network Adapter properties (in my case, a Citrix PV Ethernet Adapter on the Rackspace Cloud), clicked Configure, went to Advanced, and **disabled IPv4 Checksum Offload**. Then it started working immediately.

I have no idea what IPv4 Checksum Offload does, but it didn't work reliably on this virtual machine. Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: Nicholas... this definitely fixed the "Underlying connection closed" error for me, but download speed has dropped to about 1kb/s as a result of disabling IPv4 Checksum Offload.

Comment: Hmm, I haven't seen that, but I did disable all of the offloading functions, not just IPv4 Checksum Offload. When I raised the issue with Rackspace support, they recommended turning off offloading for Windows servers. (It used to be disabled by default, but I think they missed this detail in their new Performance server images.)

Comment: You're absolutely right. I actually disabled the rest shortly after posting my response and it completely solved the problem. Thanks again, I was banging my head against a wall thinking my code was at fault up until I found your solution.

Answer (score 0):

After changing our headers to force the credentials to be passed in the headers (via http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2010/Feb/18/NET-WebRequestPreAuthenticate-not-quite-what-it-sounds-like) this bypassed the problem.

The problem still exists that the IBM Datapower at our client is resetting the connection when it comes from Azure utilizing the NetWorkCredential (e.g. req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential).

We can't explain why it works when we run the code on our local machines and DataPower does not drop the requests, however, when it is in Azure it does.

At least we have a workaround and will let you know if I hear anything back about the DataPower issue.